# Installing flutter osx error VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

I'm trying to install Flutter on my mbp. I'm getting an error wit the VS code version, as I believe in Android studio. I've also installed VS code, the program, this is the latest version. In studio, I think I also have the latest version. When I enter 'flutter doctor', I'm getting the next list:

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale nl-NL)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 25.0.2)

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.4.1)

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)

[!] VS Code (version 1.16.1)

[✓] Connected devices (1 available)

Does anyone have a clue how to solve this?

Comment: what about a `flutter doctor -v` ?

Comment: That shows:

[!] VS Code (version 1.16.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

This is already installed. Trying again doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Try to upgrade both vscode and flutter extension. Although this is just a warning, you can just ignore it

Comment: Thank you. I will ignore it. I've already tried updating both.

Comment: The latest vscode version is 1.26. Considering you're on 1.16 I doupt you're on the latest :)

Comment: I've uninstalled and installed vscode again in visual studio, this doesn't change anything. Can you tell me how to?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Flutter. Our detection of extensions was case-sensitive and a VS Code update changed the casing in the extensions folder. It didn't affect any functionality, only the mis-reporting of the extension.

I fixed the bug a while back, and it was included in the most recent beta channel update, so if you run `flutter upgrade` this should no longer occur. Sorry for the confusion!